# Make: access argument flags

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have a, for instance, dbg executable that I compile with:

```
make dbg
//outputs: my_exe-dbg
```

And I make edits to the makefile, I would then like to re-run `make dbg`.  However, the presence of the `my_exe-dbg` prevents make from doing anything.

I would like to write:

```
make dbg -f
```

Which compiles and replaces the executable.  If I write:

```
make dbg -fr
```

It would compile and replace everything (`r` would signify "executable"). How would I check for flags and reason about them within the makefile?

Is there a variable or built in mechanism for capturing or defining flags to look for?

Is there a work-around for detecting these dash flags?

Comment: Options you give to `make` are interpreted by make and they must be legal make options.  Make doesn't allow you to make up your own command line options and/or assign your own meanings to them.

Comment: @MadScientist so I can get the functionality, according to the answer below, but I have to view in the paradigm you mention. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke make (at least GNU make, not sure how portable this is) as

```
make -B dbg
```

which disables the timestamp checks and always builds everything. A per-target workaround could instead be

```
dbg-f: # dependencies only if referred to by $< below
    # command to build dbg

.PHONY: dbg-f
```

This way, you can force the compilation by

```
make dbg-f
```

while

```
make dbg
```

works as before and checks for dependencies and their timestamps.